# Change drf action url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have an action named `image` on a viewset that serve an image dynamically. Is it possible to make url like `path/to/api-point/3/image.jpg` instead of `path/to/api-point/3/image`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @AyushGupta found the solution. I was trying to add url_path on the image function instead of action decorator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. The action decorator get a url_path as argument.

```
@action(detail=True, methods=['get'], url_path='image.jpg')
def image(self, request, pk=None):
    instance = self.get_object()
    if instance.owner == request.user:
        response = HttpResponse(status=200)
        response['Content-Type'] = ''
        response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/protected/' + instance.image.url
        return response
    else:
        raise rest_framework.exceptions.PermissionDenied()
```